# MVVM SelectedItem of DataGrid shows as null when setting it as CommandParameter and recieving it

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

**Problem**

I am trying to set the CommandParameter as GridName.SelectedItem to the command, but in my paramater command, it shows as null value.

**Error code - when executing the button**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TestingOnly.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**Full Code**

**View**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="FSQMGrid" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="Id"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
    <Button Content="Update" 
            Command="{Binding FSQMUpdateRecordCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding FSQMGrid.SelectedItem}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Model**

```
public class BasicTestModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class FSQM_RecordViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    private List<BasicTestModel> _TestList { get; set; }

    public List<BasicTestModel> TestList { get { return _TestList; } set { _TestList = value; OnPropertyChanged("TestList"); } }

    public ICommand FSQMUpdateRecordCommand { get; set; }

    public FSQM_RecordViewModel()
    {
        TestList = new List<BasicTestModel>
        {
            new BasicTestModel { ID = 1, Name = "Name 1"},
            new BasicTestModel { ID = 2, Name = "Name 2"},
            new BasicTestModel { ID = 3, Name = "Name 3"}
        };

        FSQMUpdateRecordCommand = new FSQMUpdateRecordCommand(this);
    }
}
```

**Command**

```
public class FSQMUpdateRecordCommand : ICommand
{
    public FSQM_RecordViewModel viewModel { get; set; }

    public FSQMUpdateRecordCommand(FSQM_RecordViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(parameter.ToString()); // Shows as null
    }
}
```

**What I have tried**

I have found other similar questions on here that mentioned to set the `Mode=TwoWay` within the view, but that didn't change anything for me.

**Question**

Where I'm I going wrong? How do I fix this null value error?

**Goal**

I am simply aiming to get the selected `ID` and `Name` from the datagrid and use it in the `Command` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding with path `FSQMGrid.SelectedItem` cannot be resolved. There is no FSQMGrid property in DataContext. FSQMGrid is a name of UI element

it should be:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=FSQMGrid}"
```

Comment: Ahh I see what you did there. MessageBox shows as `TestingOnly.Models.BasicTestModel`. How can I access the `ID` or `Name` from the Command class using the parameter?

Comment: by type-castin object parameter to view model type: `var vm = parameter as BasicTestModel; MessageBox.Show(vm.name);`

Comment: Would that be a good practice in terms of applying in MVVM Pattern?

Comment: why not? creating command type per operation, tied to certain view model type (like `public FSQMUpdateRecordCommand(FSQM_RecordViewModel viewModel)`) is worse practice, IMO (even if it doesn't violate mvvm). Find some ICommand implementation: RelayCommand, DelegateCommand. They are reusable and have generic versions, which don't require type-casting of argument

Comment: Thanks for the information I shall do some research on them commands you mentioned.